# How to make a hyperlink work like a button?

Tags: javascript, html

For buttons, we have the `onclick` attribute to call a JavaScript function, but how to make a hyperlink work like a button?

In addition, how to use a hyperlink to submit a form or do anything else a button can do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Href tag for JavaScript links: "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-tag-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="someFunction()">Click</a>
```

Comment: You probably want to describe the fact of returning true/false either as a return on the called function, or as a stacked command

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" onclick="doSomething(); return false;">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href=# onClick=alert('hi.'),false>Click</a>

a { -moz-appearance: button; } // or -webkit-
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/r3g9e7a2/